EventListener in Web Worker is blocked by while(true) loop
So I'm writing an emulator using html/javascript.
I have an index.html handling the gui, and a Web Worker where the emulator runs.
The Emulator works with a while(true) emulating the cpu cycles, started by pressing the "start" button in index.html
But when the while(true) starts, the EventListener is blocked and I cant send PostMessages anymore.
Before the while(true) starts, the postMessages are sent correctly.
Here is a working example:
index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Web Worker Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="sendMessageButton">Start Worker</button>
  <button id="sendMessageButton1">Send Message to Worker</button>

  <script>
    const worker = new Worker('worker.js');

    document.getElementById('sendMessageButton').addEventListener('click', () => {
      // Send a message to the worker
      worker.postMessage('start');
    });

    document.getElementById('sendMessageButton1').addEventListener('click', () => {
      // Send a message to the worker
      worker.postMessage('mex');
    });

    // Listen for messages from the worker
    worker.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
      if(event.data === "MEX")
      {
        console.log("MEX...")
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>

worker.js
// Listen for messages from the main page
self.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
    
    console.log("EVENT: "+event)
    
    if(event.data === "mex")
    {
        self.postMessage("MEX");
    }
    if(event.data === "start")
    {
        console.log("start")
        while(true);
    }
});

How can I avoid the while(true) blocking the postMessages? I would prefer to not use setInterval or setTimeout, because the emulator would be too slow.

JS is single threaded, while(true) blocks the current script completely

what does it emulate? just cpu load?

you can terminate() a busy worker though

This emulate a RISC-V CPU. It fetch instructions and data from a byte array emulating the RAM. it can also write to "peripherals" like a screen. inside the worker.js while(true) there is code to fetch the instruction, decode it, and performing the instructions. at the end of this cycle, a postMessage is sent to index.html to update the value of the RISC-V register(there is a html table printing them). There is also a PixelMap, updated with a PostMessage when the cpu writes in it. but when the while(true) runs the postMessages are not receveid, on both sides.
